# Custom adapter for navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer, custom-adapter

I have a working navigation drawer that uses `ArrayAdapter` as shown in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). I want to set `ImageView` icons for each of the navigation drawer items, so I need to create a custom adapter to use, but I am unsure of how to do that. What I have below runs without crashing the app, but the navigation drawer opens up empty, with nothing in it. Can you please help me out? Thanks in advance!

What I've done for a custom adapter so far:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private final Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
       super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item);
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textViewHome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerHomeTextView);
        ImageView imageViewHome = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerHomeImage);
        TextView textViewList = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerListTextView);
        ImageView imageViewList = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerListImage);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Setting up the drawer in `MainActivity`:

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.leftDrawer);

mDrawerList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
```

The `ListView` used:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

`drawer_list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerRelativeLayoutHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawerHomeImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_home"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawerHomeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawerHomeImage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drawerHomeImage"
            android:background="@drawable/background_activated"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerRelativeLayoutList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerRelativeLayoutHome">

        <!-- same as above, but ic_menu_archive as drawable, and "List" as text -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

For your custom adapter:

```
public class NavDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavDrawerItem>
{
    private final Context context;
    private final int layoutResourceId;
    private NavDrawerItem data[] = null;

    public NavDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, NavDrawerItem [] data)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

        View v = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerImageView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerTextView);

        NavDrawerItem choice = data[position];

        imageView.setImageResource(choice.icon);
        textView.setText(choice.name);

        return v;
    }
}
```

For `NavDrawerItem`:

```
public class NavDrawerItem
{
    public int icon;
    public String name;

    public NavDrawerItem(int icon, String name)
    {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

For `drawer_list_item.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding ="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/navDrawerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navDrawerImageView"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `MainActivity.java`, instantiate an array of `NavDrawerItem` objects, with the appropriate `drawable` and name for each, and then pass this array when you set the adapter, like so:

`mDrawerList.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, yourArray));`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
1) I don't see the source of data to be displayed in your code - you don't pass it in the constructor or any other way
2) In `getView()` you should set values for your Views
3) To be efficient you have to re-use `convertView` if it's not `null`
4) And at last - for your `CustomAdapter` override also following methods:

```
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
   ...
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public YOUR_ITEM_TYPE getItem(int position) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    ...
    }
```