# Android Custom Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to create a navigation drawer like the attached image. I've done android's default navigation drawer. [image]

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `Adapter` for your navigation drawer:

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.yourcustomlayout, items));
```

And define a custom adapter with `getView` method:

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<?> {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // customize your list item here
        // add icon for example
    }
}
```

Background and text colors should be set in your custom layout.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082763/custom-adapter-for-navigation-drawer)