# How to add checkbox to material navigation drawer?

Tags: android, checkbox, navigation-drawer, material-design

I use Menu items Icon Menu but I want to add checkbox to all menu item. This is my  **drawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox_black_24dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Inbox" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_starred"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toggle_star"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Starred" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_sent_mail"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_send"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Sent mail" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_drafts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_drafts"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Drafts"
        />
</group>

<item android:title="Subheader">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_mail"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_help_and_feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_delete"
            android:title="Help and feedback" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

There is icon and text.  I want also add checkbox with all of them.

```
[icon] [some text]  [checkbox]
```

like this.

I use material navigation drawer on my code.

This is my **nav_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="192dp"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_ist_nav_img" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and finally this is my **activity_main.xml**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:andro id="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_kitkat_height"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_lollipop_height"
        android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_margin_top">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Inbox"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@color/md_text" />



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Navigation drawer should be used as navigation, not as a multiple choice element. What is your intent using checkboxes?

Comment: If you want to customize it, you can use a Custom Listview with a header instead of Navigation Bar.

Comment: I want to create  multiple choise menu item. İt can be possible with android:checkableBehavior="all" but user cannot understand multiple choise because of this when click checkbox is clicked very useful for user experience. But before i need to add checkbox to navigation drawer menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formatting of the menu in NavigationView is limited to the icon, the name, and highlighting the menu item when selected.  To display checkboxes, message indicators, dropdowns or any other visual elements, you have to use something other than NavigationView.

Comment: @krislarson thanks your answer i guess i should change my way and i should use something other instead of navigationview.

Comment: There are several drop-in nav drawers on GitHub, you can see if any of them support checkboxes.

Comment: If you wish to add an image to the question, upload it to imgur.com and add the link by editing - someone will convert it to an inline image for you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With `app:actionLayout` you can make miracles happen.

Here's an example achieving custom widgets in drawer without any Java code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/widgets"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

#### `menu/widgets.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Widgets"
        >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:title="Checkable menu item (checked)"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:checked="true"
                />
            <item
                android:title="CheckBox"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widget_check" />
            <item
                android:title="Switch"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widget_switch" />
            <item
                android:title="EditText"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widget_edit" />
            <item
                android:title=""
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widget_wide" />
            <item
                android:title="NumberPicker"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widget_number" />
            <item
                android:title="Custom LinearLayout number"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/widget_custom" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

#### All the layouts (each is a single file)

```
<!-- layout/widget_check.xml -->
<CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="check"
    android:checked="true"
    />

<!-- layout/widget_edit.xml -->
<EditText
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:inputType="text"
    />

<!-- layout-v14/widget_switch.xml
     for older versions you can add a CheckBox into layout/widget_switch.xml
     and treat both as Checkable or CompoundButton -->
<Switch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:checked="true"
    tools:targetApi="ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH"
    />

<!-- layout/widget_wide.xml
     Just some text, notice that it's wide on the UI because it has a lot of text,
     and not because it has match_parent -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#888"
    android:text="Wide can be only forced by content, match_parent doesn't work"
    />

<!-- layout-v11/widget_number.xml
     you're probably better off creating a custom widget anyway -->
<NumberPicker
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:targetApi="HONEYCOMB"
    />

<!-- layout/widget_custom.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="&gt;"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Connecting with code

You can access it just like any other menu:

```
// <item android:id="@+id/switch" title="Switch" ... />
NavigationView nav = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
MenuItem switchItem = nav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.switch);
CompoundButton switchView = (CompoundButton)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(switchItem);
switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { }
});
```

Comment: The support libraries are awesome in many places/uses, but sadly it's severely under-documented.

Comment: Great Answer, it should be added to the documentation of the menu creation in android. Thanks

Comment: This is a great answer. Now in 2020 it seems if you use androidx for backwards compatibility, you can simply use one layout if you use "SwitchCompat"

Comment: Cool answer! This code is, with some tweaks, work with Kotlin in 2020. :)

Answer (score 32):

Alternative solution to TWiStErRob code is to use actionViewClass

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_switch"
        android:title="Switch"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
    />
```

So u dont need to create the layout file. Of course, for case of Switch, it should be menu for API 14+

Comment: that should be the accepted answer , since its the simplest .
that's weird why it only got 1 thumps up

Comment: Can also use android.widget.CheckBox.

Comment: Good one! Though I have a feeling that most of the times there is a need to add at least one attribute to customise the behaviour/visual of the widget, and in that case creating an XML is probably better than sub-classing `View`s.

Comment: Thank you.  I use this answer for my app.  The accepted answer is also great. It provides all the details.  One needs to keep in mind that getActionView() has to be used to set the state of the control.  It is essentially a control within a MenuItem.

Comment: How to make it default checked?

Answer (score 6):

In response to @Alex's answer, you can use it like this :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/checkboxX-axis"
    android:title="Show x-axis"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_x_axis_black_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    />
```

and to access the `checkBox` programatically you can do this :

```
MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.checkboxX_axis);
CompoundButton compundButton = (CompoundButton) menuItem.getActionView();
compundButton.setChecked(true) // or set an eventListener to it.
```

Answer (score 3):

After long research i decide to use custom sliding drawer. I solved my problem maybe you can use my way.So i have checkbox now.

First of all i defined **drawer_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@color/list_item_title">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="text"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/md_indigo_500"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now we have icon,text, and lovely checkbox.

after that i add listview in **activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_item_title"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i put the ListView here.
finally i defined programmatically code in onCreate  in **MainActivity.java**

```
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();     
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().     
    obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0],   
    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1],  
    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], 
    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], 
    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], 
    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5],   
    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

    navMenuIcons.recycle();


    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,         
      R.string.app_name, 
    ){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

and also you have use

i take icon and text in **string.xml** you have to define string array for text and array for icon.
i follow this tutorial for this code this is very useful you can find more detail in http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

I hope this solution is useful.

Comment: What's the `NavDrawerItem` class?

Comment: Yeah, what's inside `NavDrawerItem`?
Also, can we take a look what's inside `NavDrawerListAdapter`?

Comment: EDITED: you can check for reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27209139/3763032)