# Android - How to add a default checked CheckBox to Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, checkbox, navigation-drawer

I want to add a check box to Navigation Drawer, and I want one of them to be `default checked`

I'm using this: `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366883/6890234).

But I couldn't figure out how to make one of them *default checked*. If I use this property `android:checked="true"`, then the option is checked instead of checkbox (See image).

[image]

Does anyone know how to make it default checked (if possible, I want to do it in XML only)?

Here is my **activity_drawer.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/checkboxX-axis"
            android:title="Show x-axis"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_x_axis_black_24dp"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
            android:checked="true"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/checkboxY-axis"
            android:title="Show y-axis"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_y_axis_black_24dp"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/checkboxZ-axis"
            android:title="Show z-axis"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_z_axis_black_24dp"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
            />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you plz share the xml file you've made for navigation drawer UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MenuItem item = navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.checkboxX-axis);
CompoundButton compoundButton = (CompoundButton) item.getActionView();
compoundButton.setChecked(true);
```

replace `navigation` with the `NavigationView`'s name.