# Android - How to add Radio Buttons to a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, radio-button, navigation-drawer, radio-group

I'm trying to add some radio buttons to a Navigation Drawer.
This is what I've been trying so far : 
**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:visible="true">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/radio_buttonX-axis"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_x_axis"
            android:title="Show x-axis"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.RadioButton"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/radio_buttonY-axis"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_y_axis"
            android:title="Show y-axis"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.RadioButton" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/radio_buttonZ-axis"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_z_axis"
            android:title="Show z-axis"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.RadioButton" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366883/6890234) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53239211/6890234) answers.

#### Method 1: Add Radio Group after the Radio Buttons are created

Is this even possible?

```
int[] ids = {R.id.radio_buttonX_axis, R.id.radio_buttonY_axis, R.id.radio_buttonZ_axis};
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(navigationView.getContext());
radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
for (int id : ids) {
    MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id);
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) menuItem.getActionView();
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
}
```

But it gives an error of :

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call `removeView()`
>   on the child's parent first.

But I wasn't able to figure out how to call it

#### Method 2: Add Radio Buttons to Navigation Drawer dynamically

```
navigationView.getMenu().removeGroup(R.id.radio_button_group);
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(navigationView.getContext());
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(navigationView.getContext());
    radioButton.setText("Show X - Axis");
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
}
navigationView.addView(radioGroup);
```

But it doesn't works as expected (See Image).

[image: Improper Radio Buttons]

I tried to add the `radioGroup` to `Menu`, but I couldn't figure out how to do it either. This is what I was trying to do :

```
Menu testMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
testMenu.add(R.id.radio_button_group, testMenu.findItem(R.id.radio_buttonX_axis).getActionView().getId(), 1, "Show X - Axis");
```

But it just adds an option to `NavigationDrawer`, not a radio button.

#### Method 3

This is just hypothetical, I don't know if it's even possible or not.

1. Copy the instances of all `radio_buttons` and store in some `RadioButton[]` array.
2. Remove Group (as done in Method 2)
3. Create a `RadioGroup`, and add all the `RadioButtons[]` to it.
4. Add this new `RadioGroup` to `navigationView`

But none has been helpful. Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a radiobuttons in the menu drawer. First create an xml layout (radio_button.xml):

```
 <RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Then add it to the drawer:

```
  <item android:title="Radios">
    <menu>
        <item
            app:actionLayout="@layout/radio_button"
            android:id="@+id/nav_radios"
            android:title=""
            />

    </menu>
 </item>
```