# How to add menuItem with actionLayout programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, menuitem, drawerlayout

I Want to add items to NavigationView dynamically. This is possible with the add method of Menu class. I need to add checkbox to all menu items. This is achievable by using actionLayout in XML file with static menu items. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38492077/10716682). But I don't know how to use actionlayout dynamically in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any layout inner NavigationView Tag.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8W6.png)

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/green_btn"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu">
            **<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/ck"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"></CheckBox>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ck"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="new"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/maring_padding_20"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
            </RelativeLayout>**
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```