# Why do checkable menu items not display checkboxes

Tags: android, android-menu, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

`NavigationView` Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemFoo1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Foo1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemFoo2"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Foo2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The designer in Android Studio shows checkboxes:
[image]

However, the app does not display checkboxes:

[image]

Could anyone offer a clue about this?

The layout using the menu:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_foo_view"/>
```

Comment: The designer is showing that menu resource being used as a menu, not for navigation. Perhaps navigation does not support checkable items (in part because... what would it mean for a navigation item to have a checkbox?).

Comment: @CommonsWare that is exactly what I have been suspecting - all the issues of menu items that I am facing now may be related to NavigationView.  I use the NavigationView as an action menu in this case.  Perhaps I should change this scheme.

Comment: @MikeM. I think the title of my question poorly reflects my original intention.  I was mainly curious about why the designer shows checkboxex while the app does not.  I was hoping the tip regarding this would lead me to understand other issues I am facing with the menu.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you were getting at. Yeah, AFAIK the designer is only capable of previewing a menu as the dropdown popup style. Even if it were smart enough to know that you're using this in a `NavigationView` instead, it still wouldn't display as such there.

Comment: I'm not sure when this was introduced, but apparently there is now a `tools:showIn="navigation_view"` attribute/value available to direct the menu preview to show as such: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk0PQ.png. I just learned about it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71812292); figured I should mention it here. Just FYI. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for the `NavigationView` is to select an item at a time; this typically picks a fragment in a drawer layout for instance.

And as Mike M pointed out in comments; making an item checkable doesn't mean that it's a `CheckBox`.

So, you have to add a `CheckBox` to the menu item, and there are two options to do that:

- **Option 1:**  Using a `CheckBox` as `app:actionViewClass`
- **Option 2:**  Using a custom layout with `app:actionLayout`: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967513/how-to-add-checkbox-to-material-navigation-drawer/#38492077) for that

#### Using a `CheckBox` as `app:actionViewClass`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemFoo1"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
            android:title="Foo1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/itemFoo2"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
            android:title="Foo2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Hitting the checkBox will toggle its state, but hitting the item text will not; this can be fixed programmatically by getting the menuItem `ActionView` and toggle the `CheckBox` using `setChecked()`:

```
private final NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navViewlistener = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.itemFoo1 || id == R.id.itemFoo2) {
            CheckBox actionView = (CheckBox) item.getActionView();
            actionView.setChecked(!actionView.isChecked()); // Toggle the CheckBox
        }

        return true;
    }
};

navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(navViewlistener);
```

#### **UPDATE**

> I used app:actionViewClass="`android.widget.CheckBox`" for a while. The main issue is the the checkbox is independent of the item. Clicking it does not trigger `NavigationItemSelectedListener`. That is the main reason I am seeking a new way.

This is right; we could fix this programmatically by triggering a `MenuItem` click event whenever the holding `CheckBox` is checked/unchecked.

But the main issue of that, it can cause infinite loop; as we check/uncheck the `CheckBox` within `onNavigationItemSelected`; and that will trigger another `MenuItem` click and so on.

So, here a `mIsCheckBoxClick` boolean and also stopping `CheckBox` listeners before calling `setChecked()`, and reattaching them after that; all that to avoid the loop:

```
private boolean mIsCheckBoxClick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ....... add your code

    // Enable CheckBox listeners at the NavView menu items by default 
    addFooListeners(navView, true);
}

private void addFooListeners(final NavigationView navView, boolean enabled) {
    adjustNavViewItemListener(navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.itemFoo1), navView, enabled);
    adjustNavViewItemListener(navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.itemFoo2), navView, enabled);
}

private void adjustNavViewItemListener(final MenuItem item, final NavigationView navView, boolean enabled) {
    final CheckBox fooChBox = (CheckBox) item.getActionView();
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mIsCheckBoxClick = true;
            navView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(item.getItemId(), 0); // perform a click on MenuItem to trigger OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        }
    };
    fooChBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(enabled ? listener : null);
}


private final NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navViewlistener = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.itemFoo1 || id == R.id.itemFoo2) {
            
            // Loop prevention check
            if (!mIsCheckBoxClick) {
                CheckBox actionView = (CheckBox) item.getActionView();
            
                // Stop the CheckBox listeners
                addFooListeners(navView, false);
                
                actionView.setChecked(!actionView.isChecked());
                
                // Reattach the CheckBox listeners
                addFooListeners(navView, true);
            }
            mIsCheckBoxClick = false;           
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution.  I am actually facing a slew of issues with the menu items.  I asked this specific question in the hope that a tip may lead me to understand the cause of all the issues.  I used app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox" for a while. The main issue is the the checkbox is independent of the item.  Clicking it does not trigger NavigationItemSelectedListener.  That is the main reason I am seeking a new way.

Comment: @Hong Absolutely right.. both are independent, and almost everything would be customized; I just updated the answer for triggering `NavigationItemSelectedListener` callback on checkBox clicks; hopefully it solves that for you