# Android other default values for tools:showIn

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

When working with `NavigationView` there is a `tools:showIn="navigation_view"` on its `menu.xml` file which make its preview turn into a hamburger menu style and not a regular `Toolbar` action item.

[image]

[image]

Is there any other value we can provide to `showIn` that is default to Android platform itself? I know we can also provide a layout but what I am looking for is its equivalent on other navigation view like `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: AFAICT, that's the only one available currently. That value looks to be from [the `NavigationViewSceneView` class](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:designer/src/com/android/tools/idea/uibuilder/menu/NavigationViewSceneView.java;l=31), and that appears to be the only other one considered when creating the designer view: https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:designer/src/com/android/tools/idea/uibuilder/scene/LayoutlibSceneManager.java;l=675?q=SHOW_IN_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE&ss=android-studio.

Comment: @MikeM. wow didn't know there is a tool like this. Thanks a lot